# Django Template. Use object with highest score in queryset

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a page where I'm displaying the title of something. Users are allowed to provide their own suggested titles. The title I originally display is stored under the event's object. All suggestions are stored in their own table. Each suggestion has a vote count associated with it. I want to display the original title unless there is a suggestion that is above some threshold of votes, but if several are above that threshold, I want to display the highest one. How would I grab the highest-voted suggestion from the list, but only if it is above some arbitrary threshold, let's say 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an integer field for the number of suggestions for a suggestion model.

Then find the highest suggestion and check if it has more than 5 votes